# How can I convert a Perl regex to work with Boost::Regex?

Tags: c++, regex, perl, boost-regex

What is the Boost::Regex equivalent of this Perl regex for words that end with `ing` or `ed` or `en`?

`/ing$|ed$|en$/`

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^[\.:\,()\'\`-]/
```

should become

```
"^[.:,()'`-]"
```

The special Perl regex delimiter `/` doesn't exist in C++, so regexes are just a string. In those strings, you need to take care to escape backslashes correctly (`\\` for every `\` in your original regex). In your example, though, all those backslashes were unnecessary, so I dropped them completely.

There are other caveats; some Perl features (like variable-length lookbehind) don't exist in the Boost library, as far as I know. So it might not be possible to simply translate any regex. Your examples should be fine, though. Although some of them are weird. `.*[0-9].*` will match any string that contains a number somewhere, not `all numbers`.

Comment: The escape isn't need inside character classes (`[...]`) in Perl, either.

Comment: Right. They were unnecessary to begin with. In some cases, unnecessary backslashes can even become syntax errors (`\<` for example).

Answer (score 3):

The most important difference is that regexps in C++ are strings so all regexp specific backslash sequences (such as `\w` and `\d` should be double quoted (`"\\w"` and `"\\d"`)

Comment: What about this perl expression: '/ O$/' 
What is the meaning of $ in end of perl expression?
Another question is: When I write for example expression "^B_" in boost, what will mean?